# How to have more than one condition -> do in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I apologise if my explanation is terrible, as I am a beginner!

For my .htaccess, I've got

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value magic_quotes_runtime off

RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

so far, which I'm sure you know what it does- categories and pages. Now, I want to add something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to the end, which doesn't work, and neither does

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

work. So, would anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your original rule rewrites _everything_ via `(.*)` to `page.php`.  What should then be rewritten to `viewpost.php`?  Please give an example of an input URL and the rewritten output url as `viewpost.php?id=...`

Comment: Your Rewrite Condition checks for anything _not_ a directory or file, and Rewrites whatever it is to `viewpost.php?id=<original path and file>`. At that point, you no longer have a match to those conditions, so the Rewrite isn't triggered (assuming viewpost.php exists!). So, just **what are you trying to do?** Under what circumstances do you want to run viewpost.php and when do you want to run page.php? You can't do them both with your current Rewrite Conditions.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you Michael and Phil.

Thanks to you. I've now realised that there is no way that .htaccess can work out when to use viewpost.php and page.php, and so I've made this instead:

    RewriteEngine On

    `RewriteBase /
    
    php_value magic_quotes_gpc off

    php_value magic_quotes_runtime off
    
    RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^p-(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Part 2: of my answer- which basically makes all URLs with c- in front of it be handled by catpost.php and all URLs with p- in front go through viewpost.php and the rest goes through page.php - something I'll amend later so I can have custom 404 pages. Because I can't put this as an answer until 8 hours later, I've put it here.

Thank you guys!